# Extracting polygon from embedded Google Maps panel

Tags: google-maps, gps, kml

I'm trying to extract a polygon from an embedded Google Maps panel on [this](https://kyte.com/road-trips/seattle) website (lower half of site), representing an area of coverage. I can not seem to find any file on the website that references the polygon or its coordinates. Is it possible to extract this data or is it inaccessible?
[image]